# Работа с com-port-ами | JavaScript

Tags: javascript, com-port

Возможно ли работать(читать) с com-port значения? То есть получать значение в реалтайме и выводить его в браузер с помощью JS

Comment: JS используется в браузере и ион не имеет доступа к железяке. То бишь его рамки только браузер. Вам нужен другой. https://javascript.ru/forum/misc/25115-kak-poluchit-dannye-s-com-porta.html

Comment: @Tsyklop , я уже читал это обсуждение, там идет речь о отдельных мудреных библиотеках и низкоуровневых языках, я просто ищу простой инструмент для работы

Comment: в JS нет такой. Есть на JS, но это если вы делаете бэкенд. А простая страница браузера такое делать не умеет.

Comment: ответа на вопрос у меня нет. Но я бы смотрел в сторону Electron'a,  winapi - https://www.npmjs.com/package/winapi и подобного

Comment: @Дмытрык , я как раз Electron юзаю, все что будет с ним связано и с com-port, мне будет очень полезно

Comment: Да конечно можно https://habr.com/ru/post/264663/
тут есть подробное объяснение .

Comment: @GeorgiDzagoev , там примеры на python, я все таки подозреваю что без сторонних малоизвестных утилит, этого сделать не получится